# Screenshare error -Cannot create a file when that file already exists

Tags: c#

I am using below code to share screen.

```
namespace host
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        RDPSession x = new RDPSession();
       
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            x.OnAttendeeConnected += Incoming;
            x.Open();
        }
               
    }
}
```

In Windows 7 pc randomly i will get the below error for code line  RDPSession x = new RDPSession() on screen share.

Error:

```
Creating an instance of the COM component with CLSID {9B78F0E6-3E05-4A5B-B2E8-E743A8956B65} from the IClassFactory failed due to the following error: 800700b7 Cannot create a file when that file already exists. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800700B7).
```

What is the Reason and how to solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

When you are done with RDPSession, close the connection using "Disconnect()" function. See if this resolves the issue for you.